# How can i track the all fork()

Tags: c, multithreading, bash, terminal, process

I want to learn the number of fork() from the beginning of my system to now and also what is the number of new fork() in every second? Is it possible? If it is how can i do that?

Comment: You want strace, probably.  FWIW if it helps `fork()` is not a "command".  It's a system call.

Comment: I edited caption. Can i do that in c without any tool? I tried to use ITIMER_REAL and also  alarm() but i can't get the first fork() call in my system. @Iguananaut

Comment: The easiest - especially if you really need _every_ fork() from the very system start, is probably to hack the kernel to print a diagnostic message on each `clone()` syscall. Otherwise, you could use the `audit` framework, for example like this: `auditctl -a exit,always -F arch=x86_64 -S clone`  (assuming you use the fine L33Tn0kZ)

Comment: Actually, I don't need each fork(). I just want to know the number of fork() from the beginning. I thought if i access each fork() in my system, i can calculate the number easily but now i see that it is very complicated. @Ctx

Comment: *If* your system is otherwise idle -- no background processes running new stuff -- you can often get a handle on the number of forks per second by looking at process IDs, at least on Unix-like systems.  Each new process gets a new process ID which is, typically, sequential -- although they do wrap around after a while.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `strace`, the utility tool to trace syscall, you can trace clone, the syscall name for fork, to get the number of fork(), and by `-t` option of `strace`, you can also get the relative timestamp upon entry to each system call, which will help you get the number of new fork() in every second.

If you can rebuild you program. there are several ways to wrap a system call. you can use use LD_PRELOAD or use `ld --wrap=symbol` to wrap the fork(), and count the calls of fork() in your wrap functions. The following blog article shows you how the do it.
http://samanbarghi.com/blog/2014/09/05/how-to-wrap-a-system-call-libc-function-in-linux/